# Programmatically render a quarto markdown table from an R dataframe with bibtex citations -- e.g. for literature review articles

Tags: r, markdown, quarto, bibtex, citations

I am posting this as a question, so I can answer it for the benefit of others.

### The problem:

I wanted to produce an overview table of 50+ scientific articles included in a literature review.

I stored data of each article in an R data frame, including a column 'ref' which was a text that represented the unique identifier for that article in my bibTeX file.

I wanted to render (quarto) that data frame into a table in my output (html or docx), but with the appropriate citation, as managed by pandoc.

The issue here then is: How to go from a string variable representing a unique bibtex entry identifier in R code to a markdown citation inside a markdown table.

Comment: Or just `bibliography: references.bib` in your YAML header.  All done automatically, no need to enter the references twice (one in your data frame, once in your .bib file).  Control location of the bibliography with `::: {#refs}`.  See [this page](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/footnotes-and-citations.html) for more details.

Comment: Hi Limey
Thanks for your reply - I think you missed my point however, which suggests I did not express myself clearly enough. The 'problem' I am solving is not how to insert bibtex citations in markdown or in markdown tables -- the link you provided explains that very well. The issue was, how to do so on the basis of _data_ in a variable using R code.
I have tried to make this clearer in my original post - thanks for your interest.

Comment: OK.  So without using a `.bib` file then?

Comment: No, still using a . bib file. That was already the case in my solution. The data stored in a variable is the unique identifier which references an entry in the bibtex file ... (ref1 and ref2)

Answer (score 0):

### One solution

The following is a minimal working example of a solution:

````
---
title: "Programmatically including bibTeX references in a table"
format: html
bibliography: references.bib
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| message: false
#| warning: false
#| label: tbl-overview
#| tbl-cap: "Overview of all included manuscripts"
#| output: asis
library(simplermarkdown)

df <- data.frame(
  Title = c("Paper 1", "Paper 2"),
  Name = c("Author 1", "Author 2"),
  ref = c("@ref1", "@ref2"))

df |> md_table() |> cat()

```
````

this requires a bibtex file called references.bib

```
@article{ref1,
  title={This is article 1},
  author={Lastname, Firstname},
  year={1999},
  publisher={Charles Scribners Sons}
}

@article{ref2,
  title={This is article 2},
  author={Familyname, Givenname},
  year={2010},
  publisher={Charles Scribners Parents}
}
```